# how to synchronize 2 biometric machine uface800 zkteco each other

Tags: asynchronous, odoo-10

I want to get combine attendance of 2 bio matric machine using odoo10
I think if Bio matric machine are synchronized each other may be sorted out my problem

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using zkem dll file. You have to read all the users from one device (using ReadAllUserID to buffer the data into device's memory and then GetAllUserInfo) then call SetUserInfo for every user id with another device.

You have to have a button on the odoo application like 'Sync', clicking this button, you can trigger the above logic.

If you are like to do it over http please check http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html for api details.